# How can I automatically start a script after two scripts that worked together are finished?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I actually run two python scripts with a shell command, but when they finish how can automatically run the third?

Do you know a procedure that can I add in the same .sh to do that?

For the .sh file I use:

```
python script1.py && python script2.py
```

I want to run a script3.py after this sequence. Someone can help me?

(obviously I run the script on terminal with

```
>chmod u+x shell.sh   
>./shell.sh
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

This will execute each subsequent script **only** if all the preceding ones succeeded, that is, if all of them exited with status = 0. Remember to add `&&` between the scripts:

```
python script1.py && python script2.py && python script3.py
```

Example:

All 3 scripts are executed:

```
$ python -c 'print(1); exit(0);' && python -c 'print(2); exit(0);' && python -c 'print(3); exit(0);'
1
2
3
```

Only the first 2 scripts are executed:

```
$ python -c 'print(1); exit(0);' && python -c 'print(2); exit(1);' && python -c 'print(3); exit(0);'
1
2
```

Comment: @wundolab What do you mean by "not working"? Any error messages?

Comment: If this answered your question, consider accepting the answer and upvoting it.